# Find parent element by unique child, but click on another child

Tags: javascript, css, selenium, xpath, protractor

Trying to find right xpath selector. Element has only `href` unique. Is that possible to find element by `href="#">iphone X` text and parent class `class="card h-100"`. But click `<button class="btn btn-info">` which is another child of parent class.

```
  <div class="card h-100">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title">
        <a href="#">iphone X</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
     <button class="btn btn-info"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: do you mean `href="#"` and text `iphone X` ?? also where is your `class="card h-100"`

Comment: edited my code, sorry

Comment: you code is not complete, can you please edit it further?

Comment: edited, now should be completed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the XPath that you are looking for with an explanation

```
//div[@class='card h-100'][.//a[.='iphone X']]//button
^ find a DIV
     ^ with this class
                          ^ that has a child A
                                ^ with text = 'iphone X'
                                              ^ once you find that DIV, find the child BUTTON
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code using `querySelectorAll()`

```js
(function() {

  var a = document.querySelectorAll('a[href="#"]');
  var result = [];
  a.forEach(function(el) {
    if (el.innerHTML == 'iphone X' && el.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.className.includes('card h-100')) {
      result.push(el);
    }
  });

  console.log(result);
})();
```

```html
<div class="card h-100">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h4 class="card-title">
      <a href="#">iphone X</a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-info"></button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card h-100">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h4 class="card-title">
      <a href="#">iphone XS</a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-info"></button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card h-200">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h4 class="card-title">
      <a href="#">iphone X</a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-info"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to click on the button in the next child class corresponding to 'a' that has text 'iphone X'. For doing so, you can use the following xpath:

```
//a[text()='iphone X']//ancestor::div//button[@class='btn btn-info']
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: using this method it finds all elements on the page that have `class='btn btn-info'`

Comment: @IhorHarmatii Please use xpath `//a[text()='iphone X']//ancestor::div[@class='card h-100']//button[@class='btn btn-info']`. With this it will only look for button under div with class as `card h-100`.

Answer (score 1):

To find the element `<button class="btn btn-info">` associated with the text **iphone X** which have a parent node with `class="card h-100"` you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `xpath`:

  ```
  //div[@class='card h-100']//a[text()='iphone X']//following::button[@class='btn btn-info']
  ```

Comment: using this method it finds all elements on the page that have `class='btn btn-info'`